# Respuesta JSON de Ajax con protocolo HTTPS

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, https

Recientemente monte una aplicación web y esta funciona correctamente, absolutamente todo, el problema es que al instalar un certificado SSL, y colocarla en protocolo HTTPS, las funciones ajax que me devuelven una respuesta tipo JSON me dan error, y no encuentro la forma de depurarlo ya que solo pasa cuando entro en modo HTTPS, de resto funciona, las demás funciones ajax que no devuelven JSON, también funcionan, solo las que me dan una respuesta JSON.

```javascript
                             jQuery("#search_login").click(                       
                                     function(event){                                 
    var user_login = document.getElementById('login_username');                   
    var user_pwd = document.getElementById('password_username');                 
                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                            type:'POST',
                                            url:'wp-admin/login.php',
                                            data: jQuery("#login-form").serialize(),
                                            success:function(data){                   
                                                  var check = JSON.parse(data);
                                                  var done_account = check.done;       
                                                if(check.user_unknow === "UNKNOW"){
                                              jQuery('#user_wrong').replaceWith('<label id="incorrect_user" style="color:#d82e21">Usuario incorrecto</label>');
                                                }else{
                                                    jQuery('#incorrect_user').replaceWith('<p id="user_wrong"></p>');
                                                }                                                
                                               if(done_account === 'done'){                                                                             
                                                     jQuery('#session_check').replaceWith('<label style="color:#54be73;"><br />Logeado con éxito</label>');
 setTimeout(' window.location.href = "https://www.maseficsoluciones.com/dashboard_validate.php?userData='+check.data+'&id='+check.user_id+'&user='+check.user_name+'&permission='+check.permission+'" ',1000);                         
             }
 if(check.pw_wrong === "FAIL"){
                                                jQuery('#fail_account').replaceWith('<label id="incorrect_pwd" style="color:#d82e21">Contraseña incorrecta por favor intentalo de nuevo.<br /></label>');
                                                }else{
                                                    jQuery('#incorrect_pwd').replaceWith('<p id="fail_account"></p>');
                                                }
                                            },error:function(data){
                                                console.log(data);
                                            },         
                                        });
                                        return false;
                                     });
```

ERROR DE LA CONSOLA WEB :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (proyecto_home.php:607)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at y (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js:4)
```

Comment: Creo que el origen del error está en el POST: `data: jQuery("#login-form").serialize()...` el mensaje de error te está diciendo: `at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` ¿Qué envías al servidor en la variable data? ¿Por qué no haces un console.log (data) para verificar que envías la data correcta? O puede ser que data te dé ya un objeto Json y lo estás tratando como cadena aquí: `var check = JSON.parse(data);` pues parse es para convertir una cadena a Json: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse

Comment: Creo que el lo que pasa es que por alguna razón no esta mandando ninguna data al servidor, intente con toString para testear y me devolvio Undefined Object

Comment: Sal de dudas depurando. El error parece estar en el servidor, depura para saber si se están recibiendo los valores esperados.

Comment: Ese es el problema que encontrar la falla donde se ocasiona justamente al entrar en modo seguro, HTTPS, porque en http funciona normalmente

Comment: Usa Chrome Devtools en la pestaña network para ver qué recibes del llamado https ajax

Comment: El servidor si me devuelve una respuesta de objeto json normal, el problema creo que esta en el codigo de ajax, no en el servidor, porque debugeando, si me devuelve una respuesta

Comment: Verifique y si manda data, y tambien me responde, creo que el error esta al parsear a JSON, pero porque me daria problemas en https?, esta es la respuesta que me devuelve el servidor : {"user_name":"test@hotmail.com","user_id":"3","data":"xsH0IjJiR7acyBlGCfdD4gzXKkeFALrOESPUN5V3Qnupo6hwvW","permission":"Accepted","done":"done"}

Comment: Gracias @MarcosGallardo, asi lo logré hacer pero es curioso que en https tenga que cambiar el código mientras que en http, funcionaba

Comment: @CarlosEstarita, el problema es como `jQuery` reconoce o no el tipo de respuesta del servidor, por eso siempre es una buena idea siempre indicar el tipo de respuesta esperada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### El problema:

Al parecer usando `HTTP` `jQuery` no reconoce que la respuesta devuelta por el `endpoint` es un `JSON`, por lo que es necesario ejecutar `JSON.parse` en el `success`. En cambio usando `HTTPS`, `jQuery` reconoce que la respuesta es un `JSON` e internamente hace el parseo, devolviendo en el `success` un objeto.

### Solución:

Al momento de hacer la llamada `ajax`, indicar que el formato de la respuesta del `endpoint` es un `JSON`, usando la propiedad [`dataType: 'json'`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Ejemplo:

```
//...           
jQuery.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  dataType: 'json', // <-- AQUI indicamos el formato de la respuesta
  url:'wp-admin/login.php',
  data: jQuery("#login-form").serialize(),
  success:function(data){                   
     //var check = JSON.parse(data); <-- AQUI ya no hace falta hacer esto
     var check = data;
     var done_account = check.done; 
     //...
```

Comment: +1 **Indicar siempre el tipo de dato que esperamos** evitará dolores de cabeza y a veces minutos u horas de rascarse la cabeza buscando dónde está el error.