# Peticiones Ajax de Https a Http

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api

Intento realizar una petición `ajax` desde mi pagina la cual cuenta con certificado `SSL` a un `API` la cual no tiene certificado, pero al hacerla me marca un error de  `Mixed Block`.

¿Como Podría solucionar para que me acepte mis peticiones?
Utilizo PHP y Jquery

> Asi es como mando ejecutar mi ajax

```
var obj = datosFormS('f-login');
          obj.op =btoa('login');
      datos(
        'ipde mi servidor/function',  
        obj,
        function(){mostrarProceso(0)},
        function(datos){
          if (datos.res=='ok') {

          }else{

          }
        });
```

> La función Datos es la siguiente

```
 function datos(direccion,objeto,beforefunc,callback,errorback){  
 xhr = $.ajax({
       url:direccion,
       data:objeto,
      type:'POST',
       async:true, 
       cache:false, 
       beforeSend:function(xhr,opciones){if (typeof(beforefunc) === "function"){beforefunc(opciones);}},
       success:function(datosResultado,status,xhr){if (typeof(callback) === "function"){callback(datosResultado);} },
       error:function(xhr,status,error1){
         if (typeof(errorback) === "function"){ 
          errorback();
         }else{

           console.log('Error de Red')
         }
       }   }); }
```

Comment: **Por cuestiones de seguridad no se pueden cargar recursos bajo un protocolo `HTTP` cuando se parte desde `HTTPS`.** Estar reglas de seguridad las aplican los navegadores. **Pero!** dado a que agregaste el tag `PHP` te diría que una solución es que hagas tu propia `API` en `PHP`, y que con `PHP` traigas los datos del recurso en `HTTP`

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta es un posible duplicado de **[Respuesta JSON de Ajax con protocolo HTTPS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54460/respuesta-json-de-ajax-con-protocolo-https)** en la respuesta a la misma aparece la solución que necesitas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Respuesta JSON de Ajax con protocolo HTTPS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54460/respuesta-json-de-ajax-con-protocolo-https)